# Acessing data using next and back in c# forms 

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

This is what i intend to do .

Form 1 is displayed , requesting some data . 
Cliking the next button would display form 2 requesting some more data . 
Back button will take it back to form 1 .

Finally at the last form on clicking  a finish button , Id like to retrieve all the data and display it in one singe form . I would like to know what is the best design approach should I follow

Ie : Do i have all the controls in  a single form and make them visible and invisible .. ? 
or should i have multiple forms  with global values to be accessed in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you create user controls for each tab except maybe the last and encapsulate all the logic for that tab within the control. Add properties to the control to get the values entered on the form. Add all these user controls to a parent form which handles navigation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more , Im a total newbie to the world of high level programming .. :(

Comment: I assume you're using Visual Studio. Add a new item to your project and choose Windows Forms User Control. This will generate a file which looks like a form but has no title bar. Design your tabs in these. When you're done, compile the project and the control will appear in the toolbox. Place these controls on your main form and add the logic for the next and previous buttons there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by [IUIs (Inductive User Interfaces)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951103.aspx)

Its just like as Dark Falcon has mentioned above.. you can create a parent form and add user controls which would inherit the navigation controls and tabs from the parent.